# Run native JavaScript function on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, native, onload

With the help of you fantastic JavaScript wizards I've got a native JavaScript function that beefs up the size of an HTML5 video when clicking a button and then re-runs whenever the window is resized.

**I'd like to remove the button from the equation instead launching it on page load, remove the class name dependencies (if they're still in after button removal), while maintaining the window resize trigger.**

Thanks for your help! Couldn't do it without you. A demo can be seen at http://kzmnt.com/test/

JavaScript:

```
var clicked =  document.getElementById("buttonImportant")

  var videoContainer = document.getElementById('video_container');
  var video = videoContainer.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

  video.style.height="auto";
  video.style.width="1280px";

  clicked.addEventListener('click',function(){
    if( videoContainer.className.lastIndexOf("fullScreen")>=0 ){
        videoContainer.className="video-js-box";
        video.style.height = "";
        video.style.width="";
    }
    else
    {
        videoContainer.className="video-js-box fullScreen";
        video.style.height = "";
        video.style.width="";
    }
    myResizerObject.prevWidth = video.offsetWidth;
    myResizerObject.prevHeight = video.offsetHeight;



    myResizerObject.Init();
  },false);

    var RESIZER = function(){ 

        this.prevWidth = video.offsetWidth;
        this.prevHeight = video.offsetHeight;

        this.videoContainer = document.getElementById('video_container');
        this.video = videoContainer.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
        this.videoStyle = this.video.style;

        var ratio = this.video.offsetHeight/this.video.offsetWidth;

        var that = this;

        this.Init = function(){
            if( that.videoContainer.className.lastIndexOf("fullScreen")>=0 )
            {
                var videoContOffsetWidth = that.videoContainer.offsetWidth;
                var videoOffsetWidth = that.video.offsetWidth;
                var videoContOffsetHeight = that.videoContainer.offsetHeight;
                var videoOffsetHeight = that.video.offsetHeight;

                if(that.prevWidth!= videoContOffsetWidth)
                {
                    that.prevWidth = videoContOffsetWidth;
                    var desired = videoContainer.offsetHeight/videoContainer.offsetWidth;
                    if(desired>ratio){
                        that.videoStyle.width=videoContOffsetWidth*desired+videoContOffsetWidth*desired+"px";
                        that.videoStyle.left = -1*(videoOffsetWidth-videoContOffsetWidth)/2+'px';
                    }
                    else{ 
                     that.videoStyle.cssText="height:auto;width:100%;left:0px;top:0px;";
                    }
                }

                if(that.prevHeight!=videoContOffsetHeight)
                { 
                    that.prevHeight = videoContOffsetHeight;
                    var desired = videoContOffsetHeight/videoContOffsetWidth;  
                    if(desired>ratio){  console.log(ratio);
                        that.videoStyle.top = '0px';
                        that.videoStyle.left = -1*(videoOffsetWidth-videoContOffsetWidth)/2+'px';
                        that.videoStyle.width = videoContOffsetHeight*desired+videoContOffsetHeight/desired+'px';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        that.videoStyle.top = -1*(videoOffsetHeight-videoContOffsetHeight)/2+'px';

                    }
                }

            }
        };
    };

    var myResizerObject = new RESIZER();
    window.onresize = myResizerObject.Init;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like...

```
window.onload = mySuperCoolFunction;
```

And why do you need jQuery? Maybe you could explicitly state your goals/questions at the bottom in bold so that we can help you :)

---

If you're only looking to init another function, why not just add the call to your superCoolFunction while you're calling your other pre-written jQuery function. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    center();
    mySuperCoolFunction();    // not necessary to init in another file...
});
$(window).load(function(){
    center();
    mySuperCoolFunction(); 
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    center();
    mySuperCoolFunction(); 
});
```

---

Rewritten in jQuery:

```
$(function() {
$('video').eq(0).css({
    height: "auto",
    width: "1280px"
});

if ($('#video_container').hasClass('fullScreen')) {
    $('#video_container').attr('class', 'video-js-box');
    $('video').eq(0).css({
        height: "auto",
        width: "1280px"
    });
}
else {

    $('#video_container').attr('class', 'video-js-box fullscreen');
    $('video').eq(0).css({
        height: "auto",
        width: "1280px"
    }); 
}

myResizerObject.prevWidth = video.offsetWidth;
myResizerObject.prevHeight = video.offsetHeight;
myResizerObject.Init();
});
```

Comment: Haha.. Good point! I will edit the post and bold the goals. i think window.onload is what I'm looking for, combined with window.onresize.

I'm not sure if I need jQuery or not, actually. Ultimately this will be in a linked .js file and like i mentioned, will be combined with another function already written with jQuery. What do you recommend?

Comment: I added more to my answer so that the code would be nicely formatted ;)

Comment: Thanks Andy! I get that I can launch it in the call for the jQuery function and have tried it with no success. My guess is that the button-launch thing is making it difficult because it's getting the class involved and changing what the rest of the function interprets "this" as. It's wholly unnecessary and pretty frustrating. I edited my question above to make it more succinct.

Comment: Is the only thing that you need the initializing (onClick) function rewritten? Or does the Resizer also need to be redone?

Comment: Hey Andy, thanks for the jQuery re-write. There's a misunderstanding though. Whether it's native JavaScript or jQuery isn't the goal. What I'm looking for is removing the onClick event altogether, instead launching the function on load and window resize. Along with that, I'd like to remove the class dependencies to make it more modular. This way it focus purely on the video element on the page. I rewrote the question and bolded what I'm looking for like you suggested. Sorry for the trouble. I really appreciate your help!!

Comment: And now that I'm not reading it on a computer.. Resizer can be either native or jQuery.. Whatever you recommend is what I'll do!